# Why can't I create a Q-Q plot with R?

Tags: r

When trying to construct a Q-Q plot in R the following message is shown:

```
z<-rnorm(100)
qqplot(z)
Error in sort(y) : el argumento "y" está ausente, sin valor por omisión
```

The Spanish line says that the "y" parameter is absent.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need `qqnorm`. The `qqplot` base function is for comparing two samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Q-Q plot compares the quantiles of *two* distributions, so the `qqplot` function requires two arguments.  If you want to compare the quantiles from your sample to those of a theoretical normal distribution use the `qqnorm` function instead.